# Can I send Jsons with postman or other internet tool?

Tags: json, postman

I try to send a request to my server, which contains a data with Json (keys and values).

I see that when I choose the GET method in postman, there is no option to add the data.

Here what I want to check in the server side:

```
app.get('/downloadWithJson', function(req, res){
  var parseJson = qs.parse(req);
  console.log('static file request : ' + parseJson.fileName);
});
```

How can I check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can send json to your web api's using post method by including Content-Type key in request header and setting it to application/json.

Comment: and how I add a body? (meaning, the content of the Json)

Comment: you can add it easy.when you select http post method three buttons will appear. by selecting the option "RAW" you can write JSON and post it to the action.